# Request aid to translate from an old avconv code to ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I am working on an old script which uses avconv to manipulate some videos. I wanted to ask help to convert the following code into ffmpeg as I aknowledged avconv is not supported anymore.

The code is:

```py
subprocess.call('avconv -i %s -an -filter_complex "select=between(n\,%s\,%s),setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, crop=%s:%s:%s:%s, scale=-2:224" %s'%(
            input_video_folder+clip.video_name,
            clip.start_frame,
            clip.end_frame,
            crop_width,
            crop_height,
            crop_left_distance,
            crop_top_distance,
            video),
                        shell=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply replacing `avconv` with `ffmpeg`?

Comment: It indeed worked, thank you so much. I guess it was way more trivial than I had thought.